# Who owns a laptop that I got from Microsoft Build?

Tags: software-industry, conflict

My workplace paid for my Microsoft Build ticket.

At Build, they gave every person an HP laptop as a give away.

Is this generally considered my laptop, or my employers laptop?

*Edit from the comments*
I have had the laptop for a long time, my employer knew about it. Almost exclusively used for personal use, but sometimes when I had to go into a clients office since I had no other laptop. They are now asking for it back and I'm not sure if I would be in the wrong to claim it's mine.

Comment: What does your employer say? If they say it is their's and there is nothing in the employee handbook or work contract that says otherwise, then they are right.

Comment: The general answer is of no value.  You have to abide by your company's policies.  This comes down to company policy on accepting gifts and the specifics of the purchase of the ticket to Build.  Voting to close as company policy specific.

Comment: I would keep it quite.  Don't bring it to work and treat it like a work computer.  I don't think you have an obligation to disclose but if they ask for it you probably need to give it up.  I have even heard of employers even say airline mileage is property of the company because they paid for the ticket.  If it was a drawing at the end of the day that you presence was required that would be (maybe) different.

Comment: @mikeazo why? are other things I own theirs if they say it is?

Comment: @djechlin, other things you own (your car, your house, your clothes) were purchased by you using (presumably) the money that they gave you in return for your work. Money they give you in return for your work is yours to do with as you please.

Comment: @mikeazo what about things other people give to me, like conference organizers for instance?

Comment: @djechlin I would still say that the company could make a claim for even those small things as well. It would be silly and petty in my opinion, but they could. Consider this example, say a company offers a flat $45 per diem to cover food expenses while on travel. Let's say the conference registration covers lunch every day. Should the company lower the per diem on conference days since they have already paid for your lunch once? Many companies will.

Comment: It's yours, take it home and use it as a paper weight or whatever you want. When I worked for others I'd quite often get given a bottle of wine or something by a client, I just took it home and drank it with the wif without even bothering to mention it. I've been to openings and other stuff and been given gift packages, same thing. Unless specifically told to take it to my company either by the company beforehand or whoever is giving it at the time, then it's mine.

Comment: It's not generally considered either the company's or yours. A general rule does not exist, so it comes down to specifics. The only general rule in this matter is that the existence of such a laptop should be mentioned to the company.

Comment: I think this needs reopening. While it is true there may be company-specific rules, there are quite a few general things to say about this, and most companies will probably handle this similarly.

Comment: There's two ways to interpret the laptop:
If it was an official part of the package, your company essentially bought it when it paid for your ticket, so it's clearly theirs.
If it was a gift, i.e. unexpected, then company policy may well forbid you to even accept it, as it might be considered a type of bribe (Microsoft influencing you to recommend buying their products, to play devil's advocate).
See e.g. the [gift policy](http://www.oge.gov/Topics/Gifts-and-Payments/Gifts-from-Outside-Sources/) of the U.S. Office of Government Ethics, specifically the part on "prohibited source".

Comment: There is also a potential tax issue.  In the United States you might have to declare this computer as income. The company paid money for it, and let you keep it. In fact the company that ran the event might have submitted a 1099 for the laptop to the employer and the IRS.

Comment: How did it come up that they want the laptop back? Can you give us more details?

Comment: In all of my employment arrangements, conference attendance is considered a form of non-monetary compensation.  As such, anything that comes from it is not the property of the person who paid for my ticket, but mine...because it was my ticket. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 7):

Ask your manager. They'll probably agree it's yours (my hunch).

- If they think it's theirs, it's maybe worth objecting to in conversation, but it's not worth formally contesting, or quitting your job over, or hiring a lawyer to sour your relationship and decide.
- If they think it's yours, great.
- If you don't tell them about it, you might not want to use it for personal use in case they find out about it in the future (or know about it already) and claim it. I think this is a terrible option.

I do think they should understand you *want* it, in case their policy is ambiguous. They'll see it as a cheap way to increase your satisfaction with the job. You should *not* need to be confrontational or belligerent to communicate this.

I really hope your relationship with your company is not so terrible that you can't have a straightforward conversation about this ambiguous situation and get an honest answer.

Comment: No idea why you'd get a thumbs down. Gonna balance that one for ya ;-)

Comment: It looks like [this comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/who-owns-a-laptop-that-i-got-from-microsoft-build#comment164073_61761) is from the OP and may change your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I saw this same scenario play out, once, at an old job.  It was a videotape storage rack, "won" by an attendee who was my boss at the time, and a video engineer at a post production house (as was I).

It was a relatively inexpensive item, but the owner and the "winner" fought back-and-forth so childishly over the thing that it hardly seemed worth it.  In the end, it left a lot of resentment between the two, and I believe was no small part in the engineer leaving the company.

In my opinion, the laptop belongs to your employer, because as [AndreROIM said](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/61763/9264), it was a material part of the package your company purchased for you to attend.

My recommendation:  Tell your employer it would really help you to work occasionally from home if you could have it.

Be honest, be prompt in being honest, and ask.  It may be an easy pitch to your employer.  The paperwork and hassle to integrate a non-standard system into the network through IT may be more headache than the laptop is worth to them.

Comment: I strongly agree that the laptop is not the OP's, its their employer's.  The OP attended the event as a representative of the company, paid for by the company.  The laptop clearly belongs to the company.  The OP was merely presented with it to return to their employer after the event.

Comment: It looks like [this comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/who-owns-a-laptop-that-i-got-from-microsoft-build#comment164073_61761) is from the OP and may change your answer.

Comment: @mikeazo It doesn't change the fact that the laptop belongs to the company, not to the OP, regardless of how long he was allowed to use it.

Comment: @mikeazo - No, I would not change my answer.  I don't believe you can make a case for "adverse possession."  The company wrote the check(s), so the company owns the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

**---Updated In Light Of Recent Comments---**

Generally speaking it will depend on your company's policies. Not so generally speaking, however, if a manager walks up to you and claims that the laptop belongs to the company then *you have to decide whether hanging on to it is worth your job or not*.

Conference swag is, in my experience, each participant's to keep. I've never heard of the company demanding that their employees hand over their t-shirts, pens, or other such trinkets. That being said, a laptop is worth ***quite a bit more*** than a t-shirt.

On the Wikipedia page it lists every such convention that has taken place, and it mentions that in 2015:

1. The ticket cost ***$2095 USD***
2. "Build attendees received a free ***HP Spectre x360 ultrabook***"

Some managers may feel that since the company paid for the (pricey) ticket they are entitled to the "gift" - let's be serious, it was not so much a gift as a part of the package. This may especially be true if it's a smaller company and the price of a laptop is actually a significant expense to them.

Seeing how they've known about this machine yet allowed you to keep it for personal use makes the situation confusing. Had they immediately established that it was a work machine, that would have been fine (and I highly encourage anyone in a similar situation to hash this out with their employer as soon as they receive such a generous gift).

However, a year of personal use later I can see how you'd be upset at parting with it.

At the end of the say the most you can do is state your case:

> With respect, I received this laptop as part of my convention gift package, and have been using it as a personal machine for almost a year. It's a little late in the game for you to claim it as a company resource.

That may (most likely will) not go over well. At that point you could simply quit and keep the laptop and they *probably* won't take legal action against you. Probably.

Comment: Ethics policies (if they exist) will often state what constitutes an acceptable/unacceptable gift.  In my company a gift of greater than $75 in value is specifically forbidden and would need to be declined or given to charity.

Comment: @Myles has the right idea, check your employee handbook for the maximum value of what you can keep. I suspect this is something you need to give to the employer. It would be at every single employer I have ever had but they all  had pretty strict ethics rules due to government contracting (even if I was not on the government contract that had the requirement, the rules apply to all employees).

Comment: @Myles I'm not sure that this would really be deemed a "gift", seems to me to be a purchase. $2095 buys you entrance into the Build conference and an HP ultrabook.

Comment: I suppose that Microsoft could state in their contract that the ticket costs US$ 2,095 and includes a laptop that becomes the property of the attendee. So the company wouldn't pay for ticket + laptop, but for ticket + laptop owned by the company employee who attends. Maybe they even do state that.

Comment: It looks like [this comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/who-owns-a-laptop-that-i-got-from-microsoft-build#comment164073_61761) is from the OP and may change your answer.

Comment: @mikeazo - yes, this changes things significantly, and should have been mentioned from the very beginning.